# how to add proper html tags using javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string as:

`var string = "Digital/ Creative Agencies, Real Estate and other key industries in the market.\r\n\r\nOur Services:\r\n1.Website Design\r\n2.Web Development / Portal Development\r\n3.Content Management Systems (CMS) \r\n4.Mobile Application Development \r\n5.SEO & SMO\r\n6.Online branding\r\n7.Creative works\r\n8.PSD to HTML\r\n\r\nTechnologies:\r\n1. HTML5\r\n2.Joomla\r\n3.PHP5\r\n4.Magento\r\n5.Word Press\r\n6.Drupal\r\n7.Amazon EC2\r\n8.Android & IOS\r\n\r\nWe offer you latest technology and trends. Our Strength is technology, team,timely delivery ofcourse Value for your money."`

I want to format it properly asso that the numbered bullets works fine. The resulted string should look like:

```
...in the market. r\n\r\n
Our Services:
<ol><li>Website Design</li><li>Web Development / Portal Development</li><li>Content Management Systems (CMS) </li><li>Mobile Application Development ... </li><li>PSD to HTML</li></ol>
\r\n\r\nTechnologies:<ol><li>HTML5</li><li>Joomla</li><li>PHP5</li>.....</ol>
```

So i want to keep `\r\n\r\n` and just want to replace required `\r\n\d.` with proper html tags.

I tried extracting the paragraph using `var para = string.match(/\r\n\d.*[^\r\n\d.]+\r\n\r\n/g)` but it returns last element i.e. `8.PSD to HTML` instead of all bullets.

Can you guide what would be good way to replace required tags with html tags?

Should i first try extracting the para using `.match()` and then replace ? or is it possible to replace them directly using `string.replace()`

Comment: You're looking for [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

Comment: @thg435 I guess no. I just need to replace the proper tags using javascript regex. What you suggest is good but out of scope for my current project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue with using `replace` is that while it is easy to replace the `\r\n` characters with `<li>` tags, you have to implement some way of determining where the closing `</li>` tag goes.

I would do a `String.split()`, rather than rely on match and replace.

```
var split = string.split("\\r\\n\\r\\n");
```

Given the sample string you have listed, this would give you an array with three elements.  The middle one contains the data you want for the list items, so re-use the split method to extract out the list elements and iterate over it

```
var listElements = split[1].split("\\r\\n");
var listString;

for (var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++){
  listString += "<li>" + listElements[i] + "</li>";
}

$("ol").append(listString);
```